# disable onClick on recyclerView when is OnlongClick option

Tags: java, android, television

How to disable `onClick` when I click for `LongClick`?
It's a code from `recyclerView`, when I try long click I just see that normal click just spamming like hell.

```
 holder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "To clear your recomendations, press for few seconds. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                holder.title.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        clearPreferences(R.string.preferences_reminder);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Recomendations cleared.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: where you use this code in activity or adapter

Comment: I use this code in my custom adapter

Comment: @Rodriquez you can prevent it using OnTouchListener

Comment: hey thanks for reply, i think i cant use it becouse its aplication for tv. No touch at all, just focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line

```
holder.title.setOnClickListener(null);
```

Comment: Yea i change it but when i click LongClick i got spam from onClick

Comment: add this line holder.title.setOnClickListener(null);

Answer (score 3):

In case if there is necessity to listen both `onLongClick` and `onClick`,
Here is another approach:

Example:

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
    //return value true to make sure only onLongClick is executed without triggering normal onClick
    return true; // or false
}
```

`return true` means that the event is consumed. It is handled. No other click events will be notified.
`return false` means the event is not consumed. Any other click events will continue to receive notifications.

So to make sure both `onClick` and `onLongClick` are not triggered at the same time, `return true` from `onLongClick` event.